# React native: Inline image with text

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, text, layout

I am new to react native layout.

I want to put inline sentences separated by images, in which sentences are inline and images are like commas...

I did a json file that contains an array, which i make map function on it and in it I put text tag and image tag.

But the output did not match my design.

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import image1 from './assets/image.jpg'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import Monday1 from "./data/monday1";
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{ marginRight: 20, marginLeft: 20, marginTop: 20 }}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
            {Monday1.map((Monday1Text, key) =>
              <View style={styles.border2}>
                <View style={styles.border}>
                  <Text key={key} style={styles.text}>
                    {Monday1Text}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <Image style={{ width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 50 }} source={{ uri: 'https://www.theladders.com/wp-content/uploads/Lion_030818-800x450.jpg' }} ></Image>
              </View>
            )}
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  border: {
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
  border2: {
    borderColor: 'green',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 5,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 22,
  },
  image: {
    overflow: 'hidden',
    ...Platform.select({
      android: {
        borderRadius: 25
      }
    }),
    height: 50,
    margin: 20,
    width: 50,
  },
});
export default App;
```

I hope I gave enough information and I appreciate any help, thank you :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

React Native supports inline images in text natively: thanks to this - [commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/a0268a7bfc8000b5297d2b50f81e000d1f479c76) you can just put the image into the Text component and it will be rendered inline.

For example:

```
<Text>
  <Image
    style={{
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
      borderRadius: 10,
    }}

    // Please. use the correct source =)) 
    source={require('../../static/user-ico.png')} 
  />
   Comments like this are just amazing. 
   You can write whatever you want and after that, you can check the result of this. 
   It can have more than 3 lines
</Text>
```

[image: Result]

For sure you can combine any Text component and Image as needed in your particular task.

P.S. checked on android and RNWeb.

Comment: This causes an issue. If you add image inside text, the component starts to slide down with slow effect. This happened to me on react native model. better to use flexDirection as row.

Comment: Also, from what I am experiencing, style attributes lineHeight and letterSpacing on <Text> doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you set `{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }` to the `<View style={styles.border2}>`, and wrap every word (not a block of words, but ***every word***) within a `Text`, and setting the `lineHeight` of those `Text`s to the same height as the `Image`, and you should be done